# Unable to install Pybind11 package using Pip in Anaconda Command Prompt

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, package

I have Anaconda installed in my company laptop, for which I have no administrator rights. (Anaconda3 + Python 3.6.1)

I was trying to install pybind11 Python package using pip in Anaconda command prompt. But I encountered errors for the installation, even if I tried two different types of commands as shown in the screenshots below.

Can someone please help me? Thanks a Ton!

[image: Error One]

[image: Error Two]

Answer (score 0):

You should go to https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ and try to install the correct anaconda software with python 3.5

The reason is python is essentially a growing language with tons of libraries and modules . Pyblind11 is not compatible with python versions 3.6.x or 3.7.x .

Comment: You may be right, but I was able to install PyBind11 to my personal laptop where Python is 3,7,1

Comment: Could you tell me the version of anaconda you are using. I personally tried installing it in python v 3.7.1 right now and received the same error which you did while running it using the pip install command.

Comment: hi I used Anaconda 4.4.0 after typing conda list anaconda$ in anaconda command prompt

Comment: In my personal computer where the installation worked, the Anaconda vesion is 2019.07 and build channel is PY37_0, after the same command as above